# Consume angular 2 custom library

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, node-modules

I have created a custom Angular 2 library which is published as npm package here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-angular-library-1

My angular2 application consumes that specific library from node_module. I have successfully install it to my application "$ npm install test-angular-library-1 --save"
Please check the following code.

### app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
// Import library
import { SampleComponent } from 'test-angular-library-1';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, SampleComponent ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### Index.html

```
...
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>    
    <sampleComponent></sampleComponent>
  </body>
...
```

I'm getting following error 404 - path not found. It has to get the files from npm packages (node module) though. What's wrong here?
[image: chrome dev console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have mapped your new library in your bundler/loader.For example, below is one sample of Systemjs.config.js

```
                      (function (global) {
                           System.config({
                       paths: {
                      // paths serve as alias
                      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
                    },
                    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
                    map: {
                      // our app is within the app folder
                      app: 'app',

                      // other libraries
                      'test-angular-library-1': 'npm:test-angular-library-1/test-angular-library-1'
                    },
                    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
                    packages: {
                      app: {
                        main: './main.js',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                      },
                      rxjs: {
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                      },
                      'js-base64':{
                           defaultExtension: 'js'
                     }

                    }
                  });
                })(this);
```